# Express.js обработка url (301 редирект)

Tags: node.js, редирект, url, express

Возможно ли как то проделать такое:
На старом сайте написанном на php, все урлы были без слеша на конце, но нужно, т.е. при переходе например в каталог

```
/catalog
или 
/catalog/
```

Отображается одна и та же страница соответственно (дубль) перенося сайт на ноду, хочу сделать редирект 301 всем урлам без слеша на конце.

```
/catalog => 301 => /catalog/
```

Знаю как по отдельности сделать в routes, к примеру так

```
app.get ('/catalog', function (req, res, next){
    res.writeHead (301, {'Location': config.get("site:base_url") + 'catalog/'});
    res.end();
});
```

Только вот не хочется обрабатывать каждый каталог по отдельности, нужно как то в app.js или в самом routes/index.js написать глобальный обработчик где к урлам без .html будет добавляться слеш.

Как принять сам url для его обработки?

Comment: это express ? надо указывать в тегах хотя-бы. (express далеко не единственный фреймворк на js)

Comment: вроде бы так должно сработать

     app.get(new RegExp('/$',function(){/*...*/;});

Comment: мне кажется, что проще прописать для каждого каталога редирект. Если бы надо было убрать последний слэш, то можно было бы через middleware

    app.use(function(req,res,next){
      if(req.url.substr(-1) == '/' && req.url.length > 1)
       res.redirect(301, req.url.slice(0, -1));
   else
       next();
    });

а тут придется слишком сложную логику для хвоста писать, `.html` - это хорошо, но бывает еще и query и т.д.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov так чем regexp плох ? я с чистым express редко дело имею, но как-то не вижу проблемы,

Comment: да express стоит, спс что тему поправили!
Сейчас я прописал для каждого каталога, вроде все работает, сделал так
<pre>
app.get ('/catalog', function (req, res, next){
  res.writeHead (301, {'Location': config.get("site:base_url") + 'catalog/'});
  res.end();
 });
</pre>
сейчас попробую с RegExp, но тут надо будет регулярку поправить чтобы к .html и прочему не добавляла слеш.

Comment: а сорри я чего-то думал что наоборот надо, в чем кстати смысл этой манипуляции ?

Comment: фронтендом за задаче тоже нода работает?

Answer (score 3):

С запозданием, просто сам искал решение для express. Поставить первым перед всеми запросами app.get(...)

```
app.get(/^(.*?[^\/]+)$/, function (req, res) {
    res.redirect(301, req.params[0] + '/')
})
```